# implement wordpress plugin with php code project

Tags: php, wordpress

as everyone knows the wordpress plugins are written in object programming, my question was knowing that the plugins refer and recall specific classes within the functions of WP. If it were somehow able to implement a WP plugin, in a project with a write code, please refer to the specification.

Connection file to the db, host, username, password

set of the query

and query display in the db.

It is feasible?
are there any guidelines to follow?
tutorial?
news?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is from the official site
https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

the web has many posts on how to write plugins just google
"how to write a wordpress plugin"

aslo se the youtube

If you want to pay for a video lesson there are many just google

It is not needed to be OO.

In order to speak with db you need the  wpdb

this is the official link
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Just google and you will find a lot
In general wordpress it is not so difficult. Good luck